# Jmeter loop though CSV Data set config - Ajax flow

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and trying to carry out the following flows:

1. User Login with username and password
2. Page 1 is displayed with 10 invoices - User select ten invoices -
   10 ajax call is executed (invoice1, invoice2,invoice3..  json file is generated with invoices as request)
3. Page 2 is displayed to view  invoices
4. User log out

I have recorded the flow with blazemeter plugin on chrome.

The thread group in Jmeter has the following tasks:

1. I have 10 users in a file called users.txt and i am using CSV Data
   set config to load them.
2. For each user  I will load only 10 invoices from invoices.txt using
   CSV Data set config to load them.
3. Since I have 10 users and each user needs 10 invoices, my
   invoices.txt has 100 unique invoices.

Please find csv config for invoice below:

[image]

The problem is that I need each user to be assigned with 10 unique invoices and those 10 invoices cannot be allocated to another user.

Any idea how I can load 10 unique invoices for each user and make sure those invoices are not assigned again to another user?

Comment: invoices.txt have unique IDs? is its CSV Data Set sharing mode is All Threads?

Comment: yes they are unique and sharing mode is All threads. I have updated my post with this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invoices.txt should have only unique IDs before test start, you can share the IDs using:

CSV Data Set Config **inside** loop of users with attributes:

```
Sharing mode - All Threads - ID won't be repeated

Recycle on EOF? - False - for not to get invalid Id (<EOF>)

Stop thread on EOF? - True - Stop when file with unique IDs ends
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) instead of 2nd CSV Data Set Config.

HTTP Simple Table Server has `KEEP` option, given you set it to `FALSE` each used "invoice" will be removed, it will guarantee uniqueness even in case when you run your test in [Distributed (Remote) mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

You can install HTTP Simple Table Server (as well as any other JMeter Plugin) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager HTTP Simple Table Server]